# Hibernate entity does not update in application, it does in database

Tags: hibernate

I'm asking for your kind answer to the following: What would be the reason for an entity state not getting updated in the Application BUT it does in the database.

A simple example.

```
System.print.out.println(patio.getName()); // = "HisYard"
patio.setName("MyYard");
session.saveOrUpdate(patio);
session.persists(patio);
session.flush();
session.commit();
session.disconnect();

------MySql Database-------
id_patio = 3
name = "MyYard"
------Database-------

Later on the same application...

Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
int niceNeigborhood = 3;
Neighborhood neighborhood = (Neighborhood)session.load(Neighborhood.class, niceNeigborhood);
session.refresh(neighborhood);
String whosYardIsThis = neighborhood.getHouse().getPatio().getName();
System.print.out.println(whosYardIsThis); // = "HisYard" !!!!!!!
```

As you can see, nothing, flush, commit, refresh, save, nothing works. BUT my database IS updated, the entity is NOT.

Help, please.

Comment: Call for help is not really motivating.

Comment: try to print the patio id (neighborhood.getHouse().getPatio().getid()), you will see that your house is related to a different patio.

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my post. The right id is 3. The problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

After a whole day of reading blogs and posts, I could find solution to this problem. Basically, the problem is this: When you want to obtain an updated instance of a given entity with all its properties "properly" updated, and to do so your business logic requires to traverse objects to reach  the given entity, you need to set lazy="false" in the collection mapping tag of the intermediate objects. My example:

```
String whosYardIsThis = neighborhood.getHouse().getPatio().getName();
```

To obtain a Patio object with its properties really updated (previously in other part of your project), you need to map **House**'s Collection of **Neighbors** to

```
<set name="neighborhood" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false">
```

so as the data be always up-to-date, fetched from the very database and not from the troublesome cache.

For better explanation than mine, check the experts: [6.2. Collection mappings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html).

Comment: in short, I think what you said is wrong.  Lazy fetch is delaying the fetch to latest possible time, but it doesn't mean that it will always be up-to-date.  And, your question is not descriptive enough to let people know what you are doing.

Comment: The link above says, Lazy fetch inside a <SET> tag, not in a <MANY-TO-ONE>, defaults to true and its behavior is the one you say. BUT setting Lazy to false "disables lazy fetching and specifies that the association is always eagerly fetched". So, overwriting the default true instead with false solves my update delaying problem: the database is indeed updated when I save() a change in an object property, but this same object, obtained by means of traversing objects later on, doesn't reflect the change because the Sets in between are not updated due to their laziness. Ha ha!! That's appropriate.